# Personalization based on user's Segment

Tags: personalization, list-manager, segmentation

I'm having an issue with List Manager. I created a segment and created a list based on this segment but for some reason the ListSubscriptions facet is empty. anyone faced this issue, any recommendations?

Comment: Can you please share some more information or snapshots to explain this a bit more?

Comment: So the steps are:
1- Create a new segment in list manager
2- Create a new list based on the segment
3- Create a personalization rule for any component that has the following rule: "when the current contact is in the X contact list"

Expected result:
Item should be personalized if user is in the segment

Actual result
Item is not personalized